# Reference Error: Function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Error:

> ReferenceError: setDynaTreeCustom is not defined

add.js
Code:

```
 ......
success: function(treeData){                  
                        try{
                            showPopup("Add Fields|",'multi_list','event',0,0,1);  
                            alert("Here00!!")
                            setDynaTreeCustom(treeData);
                            alert("Here!!!");
                        }
                        catch(e)
                        {
                            alert(e);
                            alert(e.lineNumber);
                            errorExceptionLog(e,"js/request_custom_fields.js","populateTree","Custom Report","Creating Tree");
                        }
                    }
```

Diff.js

```
 function setDynaTreeCustom(treeData) {

        try{
            alert(" 000")
     ........// rest of the code
 .....
}
```

After `alert("Here00!!")` it says function setDynaTreeCustom is undefined even though i have defined in CustomReport.js in same folder different js .

Comment: The error is quite explicit. Check if you define `setDynaTreeCustom` function *before* your Ajax request.

Comment: I made a silly mistake !! not defined in my JSP file :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure diff.js is declared in your mark up before add.js